# Why would $B_{1g}$ Raman mode still exist under $D_{4h}$ where $xx = yy$?

Tags: solid-state-physics, group-theory, raman-spectroscopy

I come across some issues about Raman tensors under high symmetry , e.g. $D_{4h}$. A preliminary thought tells me that $x$ and $y$ are supposed to be equivalent in this point group therefore the Raman polarizabilities satisfy $\alpha_{xx} = \alpha_{yy}$.
However, almost all the Crystallographic database (say, http://www.cryst.ehu.es/cgi-bin/cryst/programs/nph-transformtensor) as well as literature (HTSC cuprates, for example) would count  $B_{1g}$, which corresponds to the $\alpha_{xx} - \alpha_{yy}$ basis function, as a  proper, non-vanishing mode.
It concerns me even more why we assume the Raman polarizability tensor be symmetric (mentioned in, e.g, M. Dresselhaus, Springer, 2008). I believe people must have used this assumption in determining the Raman modes, as i just did a quick check that $\alpha_{xy}-\alpha_{yx}$ should belong to $A_{2g}$ whereas this database (http://www.cryst.ehu.es/cgi-bin/cryst/programs/nph-transformtensor) says $A_{2g}$ is zero.